# Can I release an app without the device?

Tags: xcode, ipad, release, device, archive

I have created an iPad app and it is ready to go to the app store, but I can't reach the .app file.. I think it is because I have to build through a real iPad device(which I don't have)?

So, can I build the app for archiving without an iPad, using like the simulator?

/A noob

Comment: It doesn't make any difference. Your release build will generate an application file. Just right-click the exe in xcode and click 'reveal in finder'

Comment: No, the thing is that the .app file is red and it doesn't turn red when I build :( The option build for archive is greyed out!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes you can build for archive without having a device connected.

**Step 1:**
Set the active scheme to 'iOS Device' 
[image]

**Step 2:**
Product > Archive 
[image]

**Step 3:**
Organizer > Archives 
[image]

**Note:** The screenshots were taken **without** a connected device.

Comment: @Alladinian can you please tell me what will be the architecture setting for this?

Comment: @Sushrita That depends on your Build Settings. An intersected set of architectures between 'Architectures' and 'Valid Architectures' will be eventually build for your target. I hope that this makes sense.

Comment: @Alladinian this is my architecture setting can you please tell me is this right or wrong and what should I change?    the screen shots is here https://www.dropbox.com/s/yehc0kygjhqxkre/Screenshot%202015-08-12%2015.17.43.png?dl=0

Comment: @Sushrita Your settings appear to be OK. Are you having any particular problems?

Comment: error is here https://www.dropbox.com/s/pp0vj02mlu7731u/Screenshot%202015-08-12%2017.55.01.png?dl=0

Comment: "Failed to create provisioning profile." And "No profiles for 'com.abc121212.x222yz' were found" error if no device is connected.

Answer (score 2):

> As at now, on Xcode Version 11.3.1 (11C504), There is nothing like **"IOS Device"** incase you're looking for that and could not find it.

> It's now **"Generic IOS Device"**

I'm note sure but their is something about this method, it generated a very ridiculous size of Archive for me, I'm talking about 600MB kind of file, might just be because I'm building from a cross-platform perspective.

Enjoy.