# Code Sign error in xcode Archive Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, provisioning-profile

While submitting application to app store I Archived the project but it failed to build giving two error

```
Code Sign error: No provisioning profiles found: No non–expired provisioning profiles were found.

CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 8.4'
```

[image]

On Clicking fix issue

[image]

How to resolve this Archiving issue ?

Comment: Do you have a paid developer account?  Have you created the certificate and provisioning profiles on the developer site?

Comment: yes i have a paid developer account. I am following this tutorial "Submitting an App to the iOS App Store (Xcode)" on this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6uX7B8ZfMiw

Comment: Is there any reason you are using manual code signing?  If not (typical reasons include a build process that manages the code signing, shared certificates and profiles, lack of access to the Apple developer account, etc.), I would suggest using Xcode 8 automatic code signing as documented here: https://pewpewthespells.com/blog/migrating_code_signing.html#signing-in-xcode-8

Comment: What happened when you tried the suggestion from the second alert?  (Connect device....)

Comment: alert closed when done clicked.

Comment: You'll need to show your project code sign settings, along with the ios certificates in your keychain.  Something has not been done, but until we see that, there are many possibilities as to what is causing the problem (expired cert, no downloaded provisioning profiles, lack of private key for cert, etc.)

Comment: @Wwwwwwwwwwwww - Clicking "Done" isn't following the advice; it's being a robot.  What about the suggestion in the message?

Comment: I dont have device.Can I archive and submit app to appstore without ios device?.
 
.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724654/could-i-submit-app-to-appstore-without-ios-device..............
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12536056/can-i-release-an-app-without-the-device